# Power measurement with buffered solution

Tags: power, current-measurement

How can I design a power measurement unit for my slow logger?

I want to measure AC current and would like to use [a CT coil](http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/noninvasive-ac-current-sensor-30a-max-p-519.html?cPath=144_154).

This will give a output of 1 V when 30 Amps are flowing through my cable.

My logger has only the capacity to take a measurement every fifth second. I need some kind of buffered solution to read from, that saves the collected values.

Any ideas how would I design this?

Comment: I'm not real clear on what you're asking, but it sounds like you would want to multiply the current measurement by the voltage to get instantaneous power, and then integrate this over each 5-second interval in order to get the energy consumed during that interval. You would log the output of the integrator and then reset it for the next interval. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Or are you saying you want to log the current value more frequently than once every 5 seconds?

Comment: You are both right! I will elaborate the question in a few hours! Thanks

Comment: So, TI said to me: use a INA3221 couppled to a MSP430 (MCU). Have the data collected from the MCU to the logger every 5s through I2C.

Answer (score 1):

TI said to me: use a INA3221 coupled to a MSP430 (MCU). Have the data collected from the MCU to the logger every 5s through I2C.